# Time Series Decomposition on data less than 1 year in R

Tags: r, time-series, decomposition

I know how to use ts in R.
However, when I try to do time series analysis in R.
However, when I try to do time series analysis on the data whose total length is less than 1 year. It gives me error saying that time series has no or less than 2 periods.
I understand that this error is due to the total length of my data which is less than 1 year.

Could I still do the time series decomposition on my data in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post some code and sample data so we can recreate the problem?

Comment: Clearly you can't analyse a yearly trend with less than 2 years of data, because a lone case can't give any sort of trend. Of course, you could analyse a month to month trend or something similar. As @Stedy notes, some simple example data would assist with giving a specific answer.